# Dimensions of spheres are wrong

Tags: modeling

I have created three spheres (that together should make up the earth). I first created the inner sphere (the earth surface). Then I duplicated that and set the x,y,z scales at 1.012 (this sphere is for the clouds).

After that I created the third sphere (atmosphere) and set the scales at 1.017. No - a few weeks later - I have a look at the file and see that the x,y,z dimensions of these spheres are wrong. I expect the x,y,z dimensions to be the same for one sphere. How is this possible ?

By the way ... when I created these spheres I was doing [this Blenderguru tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GLIbPKpgQ4) and as far as I know his dimensions were "perfect" for all three spheres.

The earth
[image]

Cloud sphere
[image]
Atmosphere
[image]

I am not that familiar with Apply Scale ... but should  I have done that ? What could have happened ?

And is there a way to get the dimensions and scaling right (next to create the spheres from scratch) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is not a perfect sphere, it is constructed of flat faces and it is not perfectly symmetrical. ( could have a vertex at the top and a flat face at the bottom), to get it  close to the dimensions you want increase the resolution of the sphere (segments and rings ).

just consider a simple case of a circle since it is made of finite straight lines its dimension wouldn't be as expected depending on its resolution :

[image]

you can clearly see why X differ from Y for this circle.

Comment: I guess when you apply a sub surf modifier it does not improve the symmetry of the sphere ? Can you "repair" the symmetry with a Cast Modifier ?

Comment: @Jan not sure it would do , if you haven't done so much on the spheres just create one with a good number of rings and segments